# Printing a Table from a Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, spacing

Here's the question that I'm supposed to code for:

> Write the contract, docstring and implementation for a function showCast that takes a movie title and prints out the characters with corresponding actors/actresses from the given movie in an alphabetical order of characters. The columns must be aligned (20 characters (including the character's name) before the name of the actor/actress.) If the movie is not found, it prints out an error message.

It gives an example of what's supposed to happen here

```
>>> showCast("Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone")

Character           Actor/Actress

----------------------------------------

Albus Dumbledore    Richard Harris

Harry Potter        Daniel Radcliffe

Hermione Granger    Emma Watson

Ron Weasley         Rupert Grint



>>> showCast('Hairy Potter')

No such movie found
```

Here are other functions that I've written for the same project that will probably be of assistance in answering the question.  A summary of what I've had to do so far is that I'm creating a dictionary, called myIMDb, with a key of the title of the movie, and the value another dictionary.  In *that* dictionary that key is a character of a movie, and the value is the actor.  And I've done stuff with it.  myIMDb is a global variable for the record.

Other functions, what they do is the docString

```
def addMovie (title, charList, actList):
    """The function addMovie takes a title of the movie, a list of characters,
    and a list of actors. (The order of characters and actors match one
    another.) The function addMovie adds a pair to myIMDb. The key is the title
    of the movie while the value is a dictionary that matches characters to
    actors"""

    dict2 = {}
    for i in range (0, len(charList)):
        dict2 [charList[i]] = actList[i]
    myIMDb[title] = dict2
    return myIMDb
```

I've added three movies,

```
addMovie("Shutter Island", ["Teddy Daniels", "Chuck Aule"],["Leonardo DiCaprio, ","Mark Ruffalo"])
addMovie("Zombieland", ["Columbus", "Wichita"],["Jesse Eisenberg, ","Emma Stone"])
addMovie("O Brother, Where Art Thou", ["Everett McGill", "Pete Hogwallop"],["George Clooney, ","John Turturro"])

def listMovies():
    """returns a list of titles of all the movies in the global variable myIMDb"""

    return (list(myIMDb.keys()))


def findActor(title, name):
    """ takes a movie title and a character's name and returns the
    actor/actress that played the given character in the given movie. If the
    given movie or the given character is notfound, it prints out an error
    message"""
    if title in myIMDb:
        if name in myIMDb[title]:
            return myIMDb[title][name]
        else:
            return "Error:  Character not in Movie"
    else:
        return "Error: No movie found"
```

**Now where I'm having trouble**

I'm supposed to write the showCast function, but I'm having a lot of trouble.  I've been tinkering with it for a while but when I call myIMDb.values() everything returns.  And I can't seem to loop through it to sort them to create the table.

Here's what I've come up with so far, but it doesn't do what I was hoping.  I'm just hoping that one of you can steer me in the right direction.  (The commented out region is what I was doing before, just so you can see my train of thought. [the print(alist) and print(alist[0]) was just to confirm that it's one big entry in a list, not separated at all])

```
def showCast(title):

    if title in myIMDb:
        actList=[]
        chList=[]
        aList = list(myIMDb.values())
        print (aList)
        print (aList[0])
          """"for i in range (len(aList)):
              if i%2==0:
                  chList.append(aList[i])
              else:
                  actList.append(aList[i])
          print(chList)
          print(actList)""""

else:
    return "Movie not Found"
```

Comment: could you post `myIMDb` and specify more about the output?

Comment: Here's me adding two movies, Shutter Island and Zombieland to myIMBd, and then me calling myIMBd.

myIMDb isn't a function, just a dictionary

>>> addMovie("Shutter Island", ["Teddy Daniels", "Chuck Aule"],["Leonardo DiCaprio, ","Mark Ruffalo"])
{'Shutter Island': {'Teddy Daniels': 'Leonardo DiCaprio, ', 'Chuck Aule': 'Mark Ruffalo'}}
>>> addMovie("Zombieland", ["Columbus", "Wichita"],["Jesse Eisenberg, ","Emma Stone"])
{'Zombieland': {'Columbus': 'Jesse Eisenberg, ', 'Wichita': 'Emma Stone'}, 'Shutter Island': {'Teddy Daniels': 'Leonardo DiCaprio, ', 'Chuck Aule': 'Mark Ruffalo'}}

>>>

Comment: >>> myIMDb
{'Zombieland': {'Columbus': 'Jesse Eisenberg, ', 'Wichita': 'Emma Stone'}, 'Shutter Island': {'Teddy Daniels': 'Leonardo DiCaprio, ', 'Chuck Aule': 'Mark Ruffalo'}}

Comment: when you call aList = List(myIMDb.values()) are you trying to just get to the current movie key value? if so you can either use the .get() or just call aList = myIMDb[title] that will give the value of that key thats in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I'll take a stab.  I think your confusion comes from the nested nature of the myIMDb object.  To get back information about a specific movies, you should use the title as a key to myIMDb, e.g. `myIMDb[title]`.  What you get back is *another dictionary,* that you can then use to get the character/actor key value pairs.

Here's a working version of the showCast function:

```
def showCast(title):

    if title in myIMDb:
        print("{0:20} {1:20}".format("Character", r"Actor/Actress"))
        print("-"*40)
        for character, actor in myIMDb[title].items():
            print("{0:20} {1:20}".format(character, actor))
    else:
        return "Movie not Found"
```

The first print statement generates the heading, and uses the Python's format string method to get the aligned spacing that you want.  The next print statement is the divider, and then the meat of the function is simply iterating over the pairs with a for loop.

I hope that helps.